# How can you rapidly warm a large body uniformly?

Tags: nanoscience, cryogenics

Given a very non-homogenous large object (mainly water) that's vitrified (cooled down without ice formation) and stored in liquid nitrogen, how do you heat it up to room temperature without ice formation?

I have the following physics-related subquestions:

- what exactly happens to a vitrified object while warming up? How much heat energy do you have to add per second at which temperatures to avoid ice crystals?
- are there known heating methods that avoid the "surface-to-volume" problem (heating the inside without boiling the outside)
- are there physical limitations to building "reverse antifreeze" compounds? Why have we not been able to build something that stops the icefront growing during a warming phase, but just during the cooling phase?
- are other fields of physics or engineering that had to solve a similar problem? If yes, what are some general approaches?

The solution would ultimately be used in cryonics (the warming of biological samples like organs or full humans), but I'm more interested in understanding the problem from first principles and collecting ideas of how to approach it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.